# How to compute the diameter of a truncated cone?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

Let us consider the truncated cone given by $$2x^2 + 2y^2 \leq z^2, \quad z \in [1,2].$$
How can I prove that its diameter is $2\sqrt{2}.$ By choosing the points $(\sqrt{2},0,2)$ and $(-\sqrt{2},0,2)$, it is clear that the diameter is bigger than $2\sqrt{2}.$ Now, by choosing two arbitrary points $(x,y,z)$ and $(a,b,c)$ in the cone, I have to show that $$dist((x,y,z),(a,b,c)) \leq 2\sqrt{2}.$$ By using Cauchy-Schwartz, I can get a bound of $2\sqrt{3+\sqrt{6}}$ but not less. Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT : As precised in the comments, by diameter I mean $\sup\limits_{c_1,c_2 \in C} d(c_1,c_2)$, the biggest distance in the cone.

Comment: What do you call the diameter of a cone? Is it $\sup\limits_{c_1,c_2 \in C} d(c_1,c_2)$? Or are you speaking of the diameters of the faces of the truncated cone? Please update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the graph to better visualize:

[image]

$$AB=3\sqrt{\frac32}\approx 3.67, \quad
BC=2\sqrt2\approx 2.83.$$
Note: For the interested, the graph was produced in [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/3d?lang=en) with the commands:

1) if $(1<=2x^2+2y^2<=4,2x^2+2y^2)$

2) $A=(0,1/\sqrt{2},1)$

3) $B=(0,-\sqrt{2},4)$

4) $C=(0,\sqrt{2},4)$

5) $f=\text{segment}(A,B)$

6) $g=\text{segment}(B,C)$.

Comment: Ok this proves that the diameter is at least $3\sqrt{3/2}$ but how can you prove the other inequality ?

Comment: First you should clarify what you mean by diameter. Is it the diameter of a horizontal cross section or vertival cross section? For the horizontal cross section, the largest and smallest diamters will occur at the top and bottom bases, respectively and they are $BC=2\sqrt{2}$ and $AD=\sqrt{2}$ (where $D(0,-1/\sqrt{2},1$)). For the vertical cross section, the diameter (though it is called diagonal) will be $AB=3\sqrt{3/2}$. Once again, if the diameter implies the diameter of horizontal cross sections (circles), then $AD=\sqrt{2}\le 2R\le 2\sqrt{2}=BC$. Hope it clarifies it.

Comment: The diameter is $\sup( dist(x,y) : x,y \in cone)$.

Comment: usually, the diameter of a cone implies the diameter of its base (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone)). For the truncated cone, there will be two base diameters. The terms "diameter" and "distance" are conflicting with each other. So, $\sup(\text{dist}(x,y):x,y\in \text{cone})=3\sqrt{3/2}>2\sqrt{2}=\text{maximum diameter}$.

Answer (score 0):

Use cylindrical coordinates. Then $x^2+y^2=r^2$, so you can write your equation as $$2r^2\le z^2$$ or $$r\le\frac z{\sqrt 2}$$
The **diameter of the base** is $d=2r\le\sqrt 2 z$. The maximum value is then $d_{max}=2\sqrt 2$

Answer (score 0):

**Diameter in the sens of $D=\sup\limits_{c_1,c_2 \in C} d(c_1,c_2)$**:

$P_1 = (\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}, 0, 1)$ and $P_2 = (- \sqrt 2, 0, 2)$ both belong to the truncated cone.

And $$d(P_1,P2) = \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} + \sqrt 2 \right)^2 + 1} = \sqrt{\frac{11}{2}}$$

By geometrical arguments, you can prove that $D=\sqrt{\frac{11}{2}} < 2 \sqrt 2$.

**Diameter in the sens of the largest face:**

The largest face is the one obtained for $z=2$ and has a diameter equal to $2 \sqrt 2$.

Comment: For the first part, you only show that the diameter is at least $\sqrt{11/2}$. How can you show the other inequality ?

Comment: @user700974 You need with geometrical arguments to prove that if the two points are not in the same relative position than $P_1, P_2$ above then you can slightly modify the position of one of those to get a larger distance. This is tedious to explain the details as it depends on initial point positions, but easy to conceive. For example if one of the point is interior to the truncated cone, move it slightly in the direction of the line supporting the two points to enlarge the distance.